# Does 'auto' type assignments of a pointer in c++11 require '*'?

Tags: c++, pointers, c++11, auto

Given my variable being a pointer, if I assign it to a variable of "auto" type, do I specify the "*" ?

```
std::vector<MyClass> *getVector(); //returns populated vector
//...

std::vector<MyClass> *myvector = getVector();  //assume has n items in it
auto newvar1 = myvector;

// vs:
auto *newvar2 = myvector;

//goal is to behave like this assignment:
std::vector<MyClass> *newvar3 = getVector();
```

I'm a bit confused on how this `auto` works in c++11 (this is a new feature to c++11, right?)

**Update:** I revised the above to better clarify how my vector is really populated in a function, and I'm just trying to assign the returned pointer to a variable.  Sorry for the confusion

Comment: The goal doesn't make sense; that assignment will not compile in C++.

Comment: `auto_ptr` is deprecated now...

Comment: I should have clarified that I'm creating (on heap) and populating a vector in a function, then returning a pointer to that vector, and want to create a variable to store the pointer. I've edited my question to elaborate.

Answer (score 79, accepted):

```
auto newvar1 = myvector;

// vs:
auto *newvar2 = myvector;
```

Both of these are the same and will declare a pointer to `std::vector<MyClass>` <del>(pointing to random location, since `myvector` is uninitialized in your example and likely contains garbage)</del>. So basically you can use any one of them. I would prefer `auto var = getVector()`, but you may go for `auto* var = getVector()` if you think it stresses the intent (that `var` is a pointer) better.

<sub>I must say I never dreamt of similar uncertainity using `auto`. I thought people would just use `auto` and not think about it, which is correct 99 % of the time - the need to decorate `auto` with something only comes with references and cv-qualifiers.</sub>

However, there *is* slight difference between the two when modifies slightly:

```
auto newvar1 = myvector, newvar2 = something;
```

In this case, `newvar2` will be a pointer (and something must be too).

```
auto *newvar1 = myvector, newvar2 = something;
```

Here, `newvar2` is the pointee type, eg. `std::vector<MyClass>`, and the initializer must be adequate.

In general, if the initializer is not a braced initializer list, the compiler processes `auto` like this:

1. It produces an artificial function template declaration with one argument of the exact form of the declarator, with `auto` replaced by the template parameter. So for `auto* x = ...`, it uses

   ```
   template <class T> void foo(T*);
   ```
2. It tries to resolve the call `foo(initializer)`, and looks what gets deduced for `T`. This gets substituted back in place of `auto`.
3. If there are more declarators in a single declarations, this is done for all of them. The deduced `T` must be the same for all of them...

Comment: I revised my question to clarify that I'm looking to assign a pointer to a populated vector to this variable.  Can you check to see if your answer still applies that the two syntaxes are the same?  Thanks!

Comment: @ildjarn empirical evidence appears to disagree with you. I get the same results on Clang 3.4 and gcc 4.8.3. Furthermore, it obeys template type deduction: if a primary template deduces `T=int*`, then a specialization for pointers would deduce `T=int`. For `auto* p = &i;` the deduced `int` type is then 'enhanced' with the pointer declarator part of `auto*`, producing the same type as in `auto p = &i`.

Comment: @boycy : You're correct, I don't know what I was thinking (references and cv-qualifiers I guess). Thanks for speaking up, downvote removed. :-]

Comment: You should have highlighted "TL;DR" part - **Both of these are the same and will declare a pointer**

Answer (score 54):

There is a, perhaps subtle, difference between `auto` and `auto*` when it comes to constness.

```
int i;
const auto* p = &i;
```

is equivalent to

```
int i;
const int* p = &i;
```

whereas

```
int i;
const auto p = &i;
```

is equivalent to

```
int i;
int* const p = &i;
```

This has the following effect:

```cpp
void test(int a) {
    const auto* p1 = &a;

    *p1 = 7;               // Error
    p1 = nullptr;          // OK

    const auto p2 = &a;

    *p2 = 7;               // OK
    p2 = nullptr;          // Error
}
```

Comment: `const auto p = &i` is equivalent to `int* const`, not `const int* const`. In your example it is ok to do `*p2 = 7;`.

Comment: So use ```const auto * const p``` for total constness?

Comment: `const auto p = &i; *p = 3`, who wouldn't fall for that. Yet another reason for "living (safely) on the east const" ([link](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/const-correctness#const-ref-alt)). `auto const p = &i` then obviously means `int* const p`, and `auto const* p` follows automatically if constness of the pointee is intended.

Answer (score 2):

```
auto newvar1 = *myvector;
```

This is probably what you want, which creates a copy of the actual vector. If you want to have a reference instead write `auto& newvar1 = *myvector;` or to create another pointer to the same vector use `auto newvar1 = myvector;`. The difference to your other attempt `auto *newvar1 = myvector;` is that the latter once forces myvector to be of pointer type, so the following code fails:

```
std::vector<int> v1;
auto* v2 = v1; // error: unable to deduce ‘auto*’ from ‘v1’
```

Comment: Any advice on how to avoid not copying (note: my question has been revised to clarify what I'm looking to do -- sorry for not being clear before)

Comment: As told, use auto& newvar1 = *myvector; This does not copy.

Comment: OP didn't "want" anything.