# Function Templates vs. Auto Keyword

Tags: c++, templates, auto

Can the `auto` keyword in C++11 replace function templates and specializations?  If yes, what are the advantages of using template functions and specializations over simply typing a function parameter as `auto`?

```
template <typename T>
void myFunction(T &arg)
{
    // ~
}
```

vs.

```
void myFunction(auto &arg)
{
    // ~
}
```

Comment: There is a way in C++14: `auto myFunction = [](auto &arg) {...};`

Comment: C++20 will have this feature: `void myFunction(auto &arg) {...}`

Answer (score 16, accepted):

In a nutshell, `auto` cannot be used in an effort to omit the actual types of function arguments, so stick with function templates and/or overloads. `auto` is legally used to automatically deduce the types of variables:

```
auto i=5;
```

Be very careful to understand the difference between the following, however:

```
auto x=...
auto &x=...
const auto &x=...
auto *px=...; // vs auto px=... (They are equivalent assuming what is being 
              //                 assigned can be deduced to an actual pointer.)
// etc...
```

It is also used for suffix return types:

```
template <typename T, typename U>
auto sum(const T &t, const U &u) -> decltype(t+u)
{
  return t+u;
}
```

Comment: it's important to outline that auto is fine and good 99% of the time, sometimes you have to stop for a second and think about what auto is really doing http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12773257/does-auto-type-assignments-of-a-pointer-in-c11-require pointers can be a corner case for auto.

Comment: @user2485710, added more info to my answer based on your comment.

Answer (score 7):

> Can the `auto` keyword in C++11 replace function templates and specializations?

No. There are proposals to use the keyword for this purpose, but it's not in C++11, and I think C++14 will only allow it for polymorphic lambdas, not function templates.

> If yes, What are the advantages of using template functions and specializations over simply typing a function parameter as `auto`.

You might still want a named template parameter if you want to refer to the type; that would be more convenient than `std::remove_reference<decltype(arg)>::type` or whatever.

Answer (score 5):

The only thing which makes it the `auto` keyword different from `template` that is you cannot make a generic class using the `auto` keyword.

```
class B { auto a; auto b; }
```

When you create an object of the above class it will give you an error.

```
B b; // Give you an error because compiler cannot decide type so it can not be assigned default value to properties
```

Whereas using template you can make a generic class like this:

```
template <class T> 

class B {
    T a;
};

void main() {
    B<int> b; //No Error
}
```