# Why auto is not allowed as function argument?

Tags: c++, c++17

From [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29944985/is-there-a-way-to-pass-auto-as-an-argument-in-c), it is clear that `auto` cannot be used as function argument. My question is why return type is allowed as `auto` but function arguments are not ?

```
auto function(auto data)
{
    //DOES something
}
```

Since, [there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38026884/advantages-of-auto-in-template-parameters-in-c17) are many benefits of `auto` coming in **c++1z**, then why not this ?

Comment: It (sort of) is; it's called a *template*.

Comment: I know about `template`, but I am asking why `auto` not allowed ?

Comment: The other question predates C++17 by quite a bit. This is perfectly valid in C++17, provided that a few other requirements are met, but the gist of it that this is valid C++17, subject to a few restrictions, and, at least, gcc 7.1 is perfectly happy with it.

Comment: My point was, you can do it without `auto` until the language supplies what you seem to be seeking (and it does, as Sam pointed out, in C++17, subject to restrictions).

Comment: why we can just ignore `template` and use `auto` as a whole ?

Comment: as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18135593/function-templates-vs-auto-keyword) also says, why we can't just ignore `template` and use `auto` as a whole ?

Comment: @SamVarashavchik: I'm pretty sure this is not valid c++17.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik This is not valid in C++17. gcc has an experimental implementation of the Concepts TS, which is what makes this legal.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This syntax was proposed in the Concepts TS, which did not make it into C++17 for [various reasons](http://honermann.net/blog/?p=3).

Despite some critique I've outlined below, it has been added in C++20.

---

**Note: the following part of the answer has been made obsolete by merging P1141R2 into the standard. I'll leave it here for reference.**

However, even if we finally get Concepts in the next iteration (probably C++20), it is not clear the desired syntax will make it into the standard. In [this paper](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2017/p0587r0.pdf), Richard Smith and James Dennett critique the so called *"Terse template notations"*, saying

> The Concepts TS introduces too many syntaxes for a function template declaration. Some of those syntaxes have no clear, consistent syntactic marker for templates, which is important semantic information for the reader of the code (remembering that code is read vastly more than it is written).

They go on to propose a different syntax to achieve the goal, while keeping template declarations more consistent:

> => Require an explicit sigil to declare a function to be a template
>
> Replace
>
> ```
> void f(auto a) {}
> template<typename T> void g(auto a) {}
> ```
>
> with
>
> ```
> template<...> void f(auto a) {}
> template<typename T, ...> void g(auto a) {}
> ```
>
> The ​...​ sigil in the ​*template-parameter-list* indicates that
>   additional template parameters will be inferred from the declaration.

So **Tl;dr**: There are a bunch of reasons related to the standardization procedure why we don't have it in C++17, and there are more reasons why we probably won't ever get it. If I understood the paper correctly, the key point being that every template should be introduced with a `template` keyword.

Comment: When the abbreviated concepts proposal (p1141r2) was merged, it introduced `auto` template parameters. `void f(auto);` is now valid. :)

Comment: @Rakete1111 Okay, thanks for the info, I'll update the answer.

Answer (score 7):

There is already an exhaustive answer, I just want to add my two cents by giving a more handwavy answer....

In general `auto` does not stand for "this could be any type" but it just means that the compiler can deduce the type. Thus the two `auto`s in

```
auto function(auto data) {
    //...
    return x;
}
```

are quite different. Seeing this definition alone, the compiler can deduce the return type. On the other hand the `auto` on the parameter cannot be deduced unless the compiler sees how `function` is called. Moreover, there need to be different versions of `function`. While it is almost trivial to figure out the type of `x`, making the second `auto` work requires to turn `function` into a template which requires new rules and inevitably introduces new quirks to the language.

Comment: How does it introduce new quirks when equivalent template code would be doing the same thing?

Comment: @Andrew I dont remember what I was thinking when writing this ;). Consider that it was written back in 2017 and targets C++17, now that C++20 is a thing, the answer feels a bit outdated indeed