# If function f() returns a pointer, which is correct: auto* v = f() OR auto v = f()?

Tags: c++, c++11, auto

I use the c++11 `auto` keyword just about everywhere. I'm not sure if I'm using it correctly in this case though. Consider the following trivial example: (http://ideone.com/TxLJlx)

```
#include <iostream>

const char* f()
{
    return "Hello";
}

int main()
{
    auto  s1 = f();
    auto* s2 = f();

    std::cout << s1 << std::endl;
    std::cout << s2 << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Both `auto` and `auto*` seem to work and appear to do the same thing. Is this assumption wrong?

Why do both give the same results?

Which is the correct use of `auto` in this case?

Comment: I think this [article](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12773257/does-auto-type-assignments-of-a-pointer-in-c11-require) may help you.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

They both mean the same - the type will be `const char*` in both cases. However, using `auto *` stresses (and self-documents) the fact that `f()` returns a pointer. And it would signal an error if the function is later changed to return something else (e.g. `std::string` in this case).

Which to use is primarily a matter of style. If the code relies heavily on `f()` returning a pointer, or you feel the need to make this obvious, use `auto*`. Otherwise, just use `auto` and be done with it.

Note that the case is different when returning references. Those are dropped by the `auto` deduction, so if you need to take a returned reference as a reference, you have to use `auto &` (or use `auto &&` to get a universal reference).

Comment: Or, in the case of references, `decltype(auto)`

Answer (score 3):

```
auto  s1 = f();
```

You use `auto` so that compiler can deduce the appropriate type whenever it can without being bothered about doing so yourself. whether it is a pointer or not is take care of because it is a part of the *type* so you don't have to be worried about that.

Comment: I don't know!! Is it true in C  too?

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan: OP means `auto` keyword in C++11 nothing to do with C.

Comment: Yes but it is my question to you..although I will give it a try thanks!

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan: C & C++ have different standards so I am not sure how can you apply a C++ construct to C, they are both different languages.

Answer (score 2):

`auto` completes **any** type for you, if you specified the pointer(`*`) all its left is to complete is the `char` (or will cause an error if no completion available, for example if `f()` return a plain `char`).

You should bother with the pointer, just use `auto`.