# auto* vs. auto in C++

Tags: c++, pointers, auto

Is there any difference between `auto*` and `auto` when they are used for a pointer? For example,

```
TestClass t;
auto* a = &t;
auto b = &t;

a->doSomething();
b->doSomething();
```

I am wondering if they are different.

Comment: Look at : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12773257/does-auto-type-assignments-of-a-pointer-in-c11-require