# Is auto* useful at compile time or is the auto keyword enough?

Tags: c++

Since the `auto` keyword gets the class type at compile time I was wondering if there is any efficency at all when using `auto*` or if there is any particular use for that expression, because `auto` will already get the pointer type when compiling.

Comment: What is [Does 'auto' type assignments of a pointer in c++11 require '*'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12773257/does-auto-type-assignments-of-a-pointer-in-c11-require) and its answers missing to answer your question?

Comment: [auto](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/auto) I've only ever seen `const` and reference signifiers used with auto. IDK what adding a * would do (if anything).

Comment: @mojo it requires that the assigned type is a pointer. `int x= 2; auto* i = x;` would not work.

Comment: `auto` is enough. Look at templates; the parameter can be replaced by any type: `int, char, const bool, int*, int**, class user...` No need to add the `*`.

Comment: @Raindrop7 Except if you need/want to *require* a pointer. Then `auto*` is more clear.

Comment: @JesperJuhl: Yea for the sake of "clarity" I agree with you.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

None of this “newfangled C++11” has anything to do with efficient compilation, except in very odd corner cases. **It’s all there to make it easier for *humans* to write and comprehend the code.** `auto*` makes it obvious that you have a pointer-typed value, and the compiler only uses it as an additional typecheck criterion, and will issue a diagnostic if the type is not a pointer type – your code is then malformed and it’s a hard error.

I don’t recall offhand if `auto*` can ever participate as a disambiguator in type deduction, but if it did, that would be the technical reason to use it. *Language lawyer, is there a language lawyer on board? :)*

Most properly designed projects – even huge ones – should recompile quickly after changes, it’s a matter of proper partitioning of the code and having development builds that leverage such partitioning.

Comment: What do you mean with "disambiguator in type deduction"?

Comment: Nothing in standardese, but basically I mean that if auto occurred in a context of type deduction and there was an ambiguity between just two types – a pointer- and a non-pointer one, then `auto*` could make the deduction succeed. But I have not thought much about it yet.

Comment: Oh I get it. AFAIK that can only happen when `auto*` is used during overload resolution, as in a variable declaration you won't get any conversions.

Answer (score 9):

`auto*` makes sense in only two cases I can think of.

1) you want to make it clear to the reader that they are dealing with a pointer variable. 
2) you want a compile error if what you assign to the `auto*` variable is *not* in fact a pointer.

Outside of those cases, the extra `*` is redundant and plain `auto` is just as good.

None of this has *anything* to do with efficiency btw. It doesn't change the final compiled code in the slightest.

Answer (score 2):

There will be no noticeable compilation time differences between the two.

The main difference is a semantic one: if you say `auto*` then if the return type is not a pointer, the compilation may fail earlier than using `auto` which would fail later (perhaps even as late as the link stage with a more obtuse error message).

Answer (score 1):

Taken from § 7.1.6.4 [dcl.spec.auto] of the C++ standard:

> If the placeholder is the `auto` *type-specifier*, the deduced type is determined using the rules for template argument deduction.

> [ Example:
>
> ```
> const auto &i = expr;
> ```
>
> The type of `i` is the deduced type of the parameter `u` in the call `f(expr)` of the following invented function template:
>
> ```
> template <class U> void f(const U& u);
> ```
>
> — end example]

So there should not be a noticable performance impact if you do use `auto*` as opposed to just `auto`.

To answer the other question of whether `auto*` will ever be different to `auto`, consider the following:

```
template<class U>
void foo(U u);

template<class U>
void bar(U* u);
```

`bar(expr)` could *only* be called if `expr` is a pointer. And if `expr` is a pointer, `foo(expr)` will have `U` be a pointer. So, `auto a = expr` and `auto* b = expr` will be equivalent in every case where `expr` is a pointer. Where it is not a pointer, `b` would make the program ill-formed, and `a` would compile as normal.

So, no, there is no difference, except that `auto*` forces the assignment to be a pointer.